# I'm trying to join 3 tables and getting results that I don't totally understand

Tags: t-sql

I just installed Northwind on SQL Server.  I setup this simple query, which joins three tables.

```
SELECT SUPP.SupplierID, CompanyName, ContactName, ProductName, CategoryID, OrderID, ORD.ProductID
FROM Suppliers as SUPP
INNER JOIN Products as PROD
ON SUPP.SupplierID=PROD.SupplierID
INNER JOIN [Order Details] as ORD
On PROD.ProductID=PROD.ProductID;
```

I get a total of 165935 records.  I thought it would be much, much, much less.  I guess I'm missing something basic here, but not sure what.  I know it's not a Cartesian Product, but I don't know what it is.

Here is the schema.

https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/

I wouldn't expect any more than 2155 records, as that is the max number of records in the largest table, and most likely I should get a lot less than 2155.

SELECT count(*)
  FROM [NORTHWND].[dbo].[Order Details]
SELECT count(*)
  FROM [NORTHWND].[dbo].[Products]
SELECT count(*)
  FROM [NORTHWND].[dbo].[Suppliers]

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks!

I'm editing my OP...

The script below works fine, and gives me 2155 records, which is what I would expect (or fewer).

```
SELECT [Order Details].OrderID, [Order Details].ProductID, Products.ProductID AS Expr1, Products.SupplierID, Suppliers.SupplierID AS Expr2, Suppliers.CompanyName
FROM   [Order Details] 
INNER JOIN
Products ON [Order Details].ProductID = Products.ProductID 
INNER JOIN
Suppliers ON Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID
```

The thing is, I used the 'Design Query in Editor' tool to get this result.  I was really trying to get this working by tying out each and every character in SQL...rather than relying on the GUI tool...

Comment: Your query and results look OK to me.  Maybe you can describe what output you actually expect.  By the way, you are not doing a cartesian product.

Comment: `On PROD.ProductID=PROD.ProductID;` looks wrong to me

Answer (score 0):

Ghost, you are right!  Here is the final result.

```
SELECT SUPP.SupplierID, CompanyName, ContactName, ProductName, CategoryID, OrderID, ORD.ProductID
FROM Suppliers as SUPP
INNER JOIN Products as PROD
ON SUPP.SupplierID=PROD.SupplierID
INNER JOIN [Order Details] as ORD
On ORD.ProductID=PROD.ProductID;
```

Silly mistake on my part.  My only excuse is that my 8-month old baby boy was distracting me when I was setting up the query.  It makes sense now.  That's what I was looking for.  Thank you so much!